# How can I edit this Javascript without blocking functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I inherited some code that I am trying to customize and I've hit a roadblock.  I believe this little piece of code is the issue:

```
jQuery(function($){
var photos = [
'cover/001_final.jpg',
'cover/002_final.jpg',
'cover/003_final.jpg',
'cover/004_final.jpg',
'cover/006_final.jpg',
'cover/007_final.jpg',
'cover/008_final.jpg',
'cover/009_final.jpg',
'cover/044_final.jpg',
'cover/085_final.jpg',
'cover/123_final.jpg' ]

$.backstretch(photos[Math.floor(Math.random() * photos.length)]);

$(document.body).on("backstretch.show", function () {
$('body').addClass('load');
});

$('.nav-link a')
  .hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass('hover'); },
    function() { $(this).removeClass('hover'); })
  .click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  });
});
```

If I understand correctly, this script is randomly loading the backgrounds and then stretching the images and then loading the menu...

..I would like to use the menu feature on another page that does not require a stretched background, how can I remove the dependency on the background loading/stretching and just load the menu?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the load class for? why can't you just remove everything before $('.nav-link a')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using :

```
$(function () {
    $('body').addClass('load');
});
```

Instead of :

```
$(document.body).on("backstretch.show", function () {
    $('body').addClass('load');
});
```

Comment: @Blazemonger Try providing a JSFiddle to reproduce the correct behavior ?

Comment: You did it!   Thank you cubitouch!  That was exactly it!  I now have a perfectly blank page with the menu loading!

Comment: @Blazemonger It this solved your issue close the topic by selecting the answer ;) And welcome to SO !